# Product Details not showing up when using angular routing

Tags: angular

So basically I have been trying to get the product details to show on screen for quite a few hours. I have already created a `product.component.ts` and `product.component.html` which show the table data just fine, but whenever I try to use the code below for my product details to show up, it just doesn't work. Everything still shows up on the screen, but nothing regarding the table shows up when using `*ngIf= 'product'`. It's as if there are no products at all.

I have also tried to update all of my dependencies but the problem still persists.

My Product-List.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.css']
})
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  pageTitle = 'Product Detail';
  errorMessage = '';
  product: IProduct | undefined;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private productService: ProductService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const param = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (param) {
      const id = +param;
      this.getProduct(id);
    }
  }

  getProduct(id: number) {
    this.productService.getProduct(id).subscribe(
      product => this.product = product,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

  onBack(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/products']);
  }

}
```

product-details.component.html

```
<div class='card'
     *ngIf='product'>
  <div class='card-header'>
    {{pageTitle + ': ' + product.productName}}
  </div>

  <div class='card-body'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-8'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-4'>Name:</div>
          <div class='col-md-8'>{{product.productName}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-4'>Code:</div>
          <div class='col-md-8'>{{product.productCode | lowercase | convertToSpaces: '-'}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-4'>Description:</div>
          <div class='col-md-8'>{{product.description}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-4'>Availability:</div>
          <div class='col-md-8'>{{product.releaseDate}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-4'>Price:</div>
          <div class='col-md-8'>{{product.price|currency:'USD':'symbol'}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-4'>5 Star Rating:</div>
          <div class='col-md-8'>
            <pm-star [rating]='product.starRating'>
            </pm-star>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <img class='center-block img-responsive'
             [style.width.px]='200'
             [style.margin.px]='2'
             [src]='product.imageUrl'
             [title]='product.productName'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='card-footer'>
    <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary'
            (click)='onBack()'
            style='width:80px'>
      <i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i> Back
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';
import { ProductDetailComponent } from './products/product-detail.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './products/product-list.component';
import { ProductDetailGuard } from './products/product-detail.guard';
import { ConvertToSpacesPipe } from './shared/convert-to-spaces.pipe';
import { StarComponent } from './shared/star.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    ProductDetailComponent,
    ConvertToSpacesPipe,
    StarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent },
      {
        path: 'products/:id',
        canActivate: [ProductDetailGuard],
        component: ProductDetailComponent
      },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]),
  ],
  providers:[ YachtService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: can you please tell what error you getting

Comment: I am getting no errors, neither in the terminal nor in the browser except the usual ones that I had  long before the problem:  First = 1:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. second= prompt.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'originalPrompt' has already been declared   Third = Uncaught (in promise)

Comment: so what you trying to do buddy

Comment: I'm trying to show product details of the clicked items .

Comment: Can you post this in stackblitz? There's alot of code to go through..

Comment: Just a random guess.. in component onInit if it did'nt get  the param it basically caters nothing right?? Did you double check there?

Comment: I need that part because I have an ngOnInit method

Comment: "It's as if there are no products at all." Well have you checked to see if ```getProduct()``` is actually returning anything? Also, ```product: IProduct | undefined;``` doesn't make any sense as it's already undefined, so what is the point of this?

Comment: Are you seeing anything come back in the Network tab of the console?

Comment: i removed the |undefined and it still doesn't work.  and nothing is showing on the network tab, there is an error though  : Uncaught (in promise) and i think it has something to do with this

Answer (score 0):

ProductService is not incluided in the module providers

```
providers:[ ProductService ]
```

or providedIn root

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
```

Comment: Add the code of your service `ProductService`, apparently, you are not returning the observable correctly